# Have to remove lines in header and footer in pdf using iText java

Tags: java, itext

```
    I've used the following code to display header and footer in my pdf using itext.

   HeaderFooter header=new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("HBOM Reports"),false);
                document.setHeader(header);
                HeaderFooter footer=new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("globematics\nSecond line"),false);
                document.setFooter(footer);
```

Here is my header  displayed output in my pdf

---

HBOM Reports

---

My footer displayed as like this

---

globematics

second line

---

Now I don't know why the two lines are printing on my header and footer.

- I want to remove the bottom line from my footer and top line from  my
         header. And I need to align both header and footer text in Center.

  Just now I started using iText so I don't have any idea in that.Please some help me for this.
      Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setAlignement` to center the text, and `setBorder` to remove the border and add only the one you want.

```
HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("HBOM Reports"), false);
header.setAlignment(HeaderFooter.ALIGN_CENTER);
header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER); 
header.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
document.setHeader(header);

HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("globematics\nSecond line"), false);
footer.setAlignment(HeaderFooter.ALIGN_CENTER);
footer.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER); 
footer.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
document.setFooter(footer);
```

As I have seen multiple times on the web, the use of this class is discouraged, you may take a look at [page events](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=204)

Comment: I can't see the contents on that site.It given only the topics